# organizing large pieces of code

Tags: code-organization

I was wondering what methods of code organization stackoverflow users use. I have a sporadic thought process and as a result my code can start to look messy and over whelming. Any tips ?

Comment: Are you looking for someone to tell you to refactor?  With a vague question like this, all we can give is vague advice -- like "you should refactor".  Perhaps if you gave some clue as to what you're talking about, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep methods short and give classes a single, clear responsibility.

It's not necessary, but TDD can help you acheive this

Comment: +1 this was pretty much what I answered, just noticed you beat me to it

Answer (score 1):

One file per class.

Folders for related classes.

Use modules/packages/assemblies/namespaces if your language supports them.

In general, keep many levels of abstraction, and try to keep them separate through whatever mechanism you can in your language/ide/platform of choice.

Read [Domain Driven Design](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Domain-driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215), which discusses these issues (design, documentation, organization and communication).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at the principles of [Large Scale C++ Software Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633620) by John Lakos (ISBN-13: 978-0201633627) if not the [book itself](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0201633620). They are summed up in these [lecture notes](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~kettner/courses/lib_design_03/notes/large.html). Another [summary of ideas](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~stotts/COMP204/lakos/).

Here's a brief outline of the headings of the principles, which while written about in the C++ context, the geist of which are language agnostic.

- Internal and External Linkage
- Components and Dependency Relations
- Physical Hierarchy Reducing Link-Time
- Dependencies: Levelization Reducing
- Compile-Time Dependencies: Insulation